# Find cell with highest value of a cell range

Tags: google-sheets

I have a row of percent values. In the last of the row (Column E) I want the text to appear, that is in the very first row above the values:

```
A       B      C       D         E
-----------------------------------
foo    bar    test    foobar
-----------------------------------
10%    13%     3%      1%      bar
-----------------------------------
1%    13%     30%      1%      test
-----------------------------------
9%     3%      3%      11%     foobar
```

What's the formula to put in the cells in column E?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This formula should do the trick for the first row:

```
=INDEX(A$1:D$1, 1, MATCH(MAX(A2:D2), A2:D2, 0))
```

Drag the formula across to the other rows, and the `A2:D2` range should automatically be adjusted to `A3:D3`, `A4:D4` etc.

Explanation:

- The `MAX` function returns the highest value of the range `A2:D2`. For row 2, this would be `13%`.
- Next, the `MATCH` function returns the index of that value within the given range. This would be `2` (column `B`).
- Finally, `INDEX` returns the value of a cell in the `A1:D1` range, row `1`, with the index returned from `MATCH` as column index.

Feel free to copy [the example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uzO68eXtlkvzIDIBguHNIdF4OlQSfchFEj7mkU2reJI/edit?usp=sharing) I've set up. Also, refer to the [Google Spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks so far. But the Match function seems to have an error. "Error parsing function".

Comment: Okay, I had to use semicolons because I'm in a different locale. Works now!

Comment: OK, good :) The `;` vs `,` is a locale issue.

Comment: What if there are 2 rows matching the max value?

Comment: @Gerbus I guess you mean "What if there are 2 _columns_ matching the max value?". `MATCH` only returns a single value, so the result will be the heading of the first column with the max value. So if  `A=3`, `B=2`, `C=3`, the result will be `A`.